# how to restrict digitally signed PDF from online PDF editor Tools

Tags: java

iam genarating digitally signed PDF, once PDF generated it can able to edit by using online editor tools
here iam using qoppa jar
how to restrict please help me out

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your specific problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though a document with a digital signature will still be editable with some tools, if there are any changes made to the document, the digital signature will become invalid, which will show anytime the document is opened after that.

Instead of digital signature, another option is to set a password and restrict permissions on the document.  Most editors will not change a document that is setup this way, although enforcing the permissions is still optional, so some editors might still allow you to edit.